# Solving an equation involving the integer part

Tags: congruences, integers

Let $[x]$ denote the integer part of $x\in R$. Let consider the following equation:

$$
[\sqrt {x+1} \,]=[\sqrt{x}],\; x\in N.  \;\; (Eq).
$$
Using the definition of the integer part, one can show that elements $x\in N$ such that: $x\equiv 1 $ mod $4$ or $x\equiv 2  $ mod $ 4 $ are all solutions of (Eq).

My question is as follows: among integers $x$ such that $x\equiv 0 $ mod $4$, which ones are solutions of (Eq)?
Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Well integers such that $x+1\neq t^2$ are solutions of the equation.

Comment: All except $4n(n+1).$

Comment: @ProfessorVector: I don't follow.  Are you saying that $[\sqrt{4n(n-1)+1}] = [\sqrt{4n(n-1)}]$ for all $n$?

Comment: "All _except_" means they are _not_ solutions: in fact $[\sqrt{4n(n+1)+1}]=2n+1>[\sqrt{4n(n+1)}]=2n$, while all other numbers divisible by 4 are solutions.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Ah. I misread it what you wrote as $4n(n-1)$ (as my comment above might indicate.

Comment: Now _that_ wouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: That was my point.  Please also use "@username" when resounding to a comment so I know there's one here!  Furthermore I still take issue with your original comment.  $4n(n+1) = (2n+1)^2 - 1$, so it falls under the comment of kingW3.  You could also say the same for $3n(3n+2)$ for instance as well.  So I don't understand the intention of your comment.

Comment: @JavaMan Correct, I pointed out those numbers mentioned by kingW3 satisfying the condition $x\equiv0\mod4$ imposed by the OP. "I don't understand" is not a very strong argument (not only) in mathematics, but that's your choice. I won't waste your time any more.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments..

Answer (score 2):

If $x+1$ is a square, then $[\sqrt{x+1}]=[\sqrt{x}]+1\neq[\sqrt{x}]$

Conversely, $[\sqrt{x+1}]\neq[\sqrt{x}]$ and $x\in \mathbb{N}$ implies $x+1$ is a square.

So the solutions of the equation are $\mathbb{N}-\{n^2-1, n\in \mathbb{N}\}=\{1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10...\}$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ has a unit jump at every perfect square, and so has the sequence of $\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor$, shifted by one.

$$0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,\cdots$$ vs

$$1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3\cdots$$